Import Bootstrap component in scss module
Can I do the following in a Nextjs project?
I have a global.scss file where I import the necessary Bootstrap scss files, but I don't want to load everything, only when I need them, for example when I import a component.
I have an scss module for each component, e.g. src/components/global-nav/global-nav.module.scss where I tried to import the modal.scss without success:
@import "../../styles/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";

In the global-nav.tsx file I import like this: import styles from './global-nav.module.scss'; and everything else if working apart from the modal style.
In next.config js file I have:
sassOptions: {include paths: ["node_modules", "./node_modules"]} but I didn't help.


Avoid using newer version, remove~.
try using this sassOptions: { includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles'), 'node_modules'], }


Thank you @Tanmay Nandwana, but unfortunately, none of these suggestions works. It doesn't load it.
